# new retrieved list of the selected item from a list

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I have a list which retrieves data from an object from backend, and after selecting an item from that list, it should display its items but i don't know how to render that in html or in rxjs.

Here is my current state after selecting the item `Test1` from the list, it retrieve its inner items that are `info 1` and `info 2`.

```
List:
  List: Array(2)
     0: {name: "Test1", item: Array(2)}
     1: {name: "Test2", item: Array(1)}
     length: 2
     __proto__: Array(0)
   selectedItemData: Array(2)
     0: {name: "info 1", item: Array(1)}
     1: {name: "info 2", item: Array(4)}
```

But the list doesn't change, even though everything works concerning the retrieving part of each selected item.

Here is my html :

```
      <ul class="unstyled" *ngFor="let i of (listObservable$|async).list.List">
        <li><a (click)="selected(i.name)">{{i.name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Should `(listObservable$|async).list` be uppercase `List` like this `(listObservable$|async).List`?

Comment: it's actually (listObservable$|async).list.List, sorry it was a mistake, i updated with my model

Answer (score 1):

When using the async pipe it is best to us an ngIf and map it to a view variable so you only render the element once the observable has emitted.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="listObservable$ | async as listObj">
  <ul class="unstyled" *ngFor="let i of listObj.list.List">
    <li><a (click)="selected(i.name)">{{i.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```